# Issue with null character in Cython

Tags: python, cython

The following Cython code is not working as expected.

```
cdef char* char_tester():
    py_str = "a\0b\0c".encode("UTF-8")
    cdef char* c_str = py_str
    return c_str   

def test():
    print(char_tester())
    cdef char* my_str = char_tester()
    for i in range(5):
        print(my_str[i])

>>> test()
b'a'
97
55
10
0
99
```

I would expect the code to be printing out the byte string 'a b c', and the ASCII values 97, 0, 98, 0, 99, in that order. Moreover, when I add the for loop for printing the characters inside the for loop, I get the expected ASCII values as output. Apparently, the `char*`returned by `char_tester`is being truncated somehow in the `test()`function. How do I prevent this from happening, and get the expected output?

Comment: Did you look at [the documentation](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/strings.html)?  I would assume that calling the C function from the Python function converts the `char*` to a Python string and treats it as a null-terminated string.

Comment: Yes, but i specified the type of the variable in the line:
cdef char* my_str = char_tester(), so that should be irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assigment `cdef char * s = py_str` points to a memory location that is invalid after `char_tester()` returns. It is like a the case when a C function returns an address to local stack allocated variable, undefined behaviour.

With the following function

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc
from libc.string cimport memcpy

cdef char* char_tester():
    py_str = "a\0b\0c".encode("UTF-8")
    cdef char* c_str
    cdef char * s = py_str
    cdef ssize_t slen = len(py_str)

    c_str = <char *>malloc((slen+1)*sizeof(char))
    memcpy(c_str, s, slen)
    c_str[slen] = '\0'
    return c_str
```

the test code will print (python 3.4)

```
b'a'
97
0
98
0
99
```

Comment: That extra `\0` at the end of char array is probably not needed in this case since there are already '\0'.